# How do I store messages like iMessage does?

Tags: ios, react-native

How does iMessage instantly have all your texts there when you open a conversation? Does iMessage save it into something like Firebase or Asyncstorage ??

I am making a chat app and I am wondering how to do this efficiently, right now I am downloading messages from the server every time the user opens the conversation, but given how fast iMessage is it seems it may be more efficient to save the messages somewhere on the phone itself?

Comment: " I am wondering how to do this efficiently" Start by figuring out how to do it. Don't worry about efficiency until you have a working solution.

Comment: ^^ I agree with the above. You could probably then move to using some sort of high-performance cache locally to keep track of recent n messages and then load more when connected to a server. But I have no idea how Apple actually does it.

Comment: *"it seems it may be more efficient to save the messages somewhere on the phone itself?"* - If you're asking whether it's faster to request data from a local device than from a network connection, the answer is almost always yes.  Was that really all you wanted to know?  You could always try both and measure the differences...

Comment: I should've clarified earlier: I do have a working chat app that is socket based and loads messages from the server each time a conversation is opened. More clearly stated, my question was what is the most efficient way to cache/store messages to be immediately available (the way iMsgs are). rb615's answer is what I was looking for. It makes sense to store a small number of messages locally.

Comment: Not sure about efficiency, But you can store all the messages. You have to add Notification service extention to your iOS app, also allow access to App Groups. Now create a database and access that database using App Groups, in your extention. Everytime a user has to receive a message send it with push notification, if the app is active, don't show push notification and when app is  in closed/background state, show notification. But make sure you store all the notifications in your database. And next time you launch app, load data from local database. I hope this helps.